# What is an XDM file in the context of AUTOSAR?

Tags: embedded, autosar, automotive

I'm working on an AUTOSAR project and I've come across references to both XDM files and ARXML files, but I'm a bit confused about their purposes and differences and searching on Google did not help.
Can someone provide a clear explanation of:

- What is an XDM file in the context of AUTOSAR?
- How do XDM files differ from ARXML files? Are there specific use cases for each?
- When should one choose to use an XDM file over an ARXML file (or vice versa)?
- Are there any constraints or considerations that developers should be aware of when selecting between XDM and ARXML files for their project?

I'm looking to understand the role of these file formats in AUTOSAR development and make informed decisions for my project. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elektrobit uses XDM files to store the EcuC configurations of BSW modules in Tresos Studio.

They might also be XML files, but they are not ARXML files. You can convert/export them to ARXML files though. They are based on a different kind of XML schema.

Stay with the ARXML files in the first place, and only care about XDM at the point you really need to fiddle around with their configuration files.

All AUTOSAR tools will understand ARXML.

Comment: Thanks alot @kesselhaus, for answer, I got it, but then there also one scenario where all the XDM files are in use, and also its placed in one big ARXML, so in what condition we are using this?

Comment: There are some ARXML files (usually in /SystemModel subdirectory of the Tresos configuration), which are generated at ARXML Import (e.g. SystemDescription/EcuExtract import to create/update the SystemModel and configuration due to changes in the imported files) and on ARXML Export (e.g. when generating the RTE and BSW config). Also in the /generated or such directory some ARXMLs (e.g. SWCDs and BSWMDs are generated).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever XDM stands for, it is not an official AUTOSAR file format. The only format in which models and configuration can be exchanged in conformance with the standard is ARXML.